# Retrieve Data for SSL Tracking

Tags: c#, ssl, ssl-certificate

I need to write an app that retrieves data on expiring SSL certs. What is the best way to locate this data for application purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[X509Certificate2 Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.aspx):

- [NotBefore Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.notbefore(v=VS.100).aspx) - Gets the date in local time on which a certificate becomes valid.
- [NotAfter Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.notafter(v=VS.100).aspx) - Gets the date in local time after which a certificate is no longer valid.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will be writing this application in the upcoming month and let you know how it works out.

Answer (score 1):

For your reference, here are a few applications that do this type of thing. They may give you some ideas regarding features and interface.

[cert scanner](http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/tools/18331.html)

[checkcertificate](http://prefetch.net/articles/checkcertificate.html)

[certificate expiry reporter](http://www.novell.com/communities/node/2309/pki%20certificate%20expiry%20reporter)

[cert expiry checker](http://www.redkestrel.co.uk/cgi/certchecker.pl)